# How do I see list of collection groups when exporting?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using Google Cloud Firestore in **Native Mode**, but I cannot export collection groups because they do not appear in the dropdown list. I already have data with different collections. Just for reference, my data structure looks like this

```
root/
  chat_events/ (collection)
    doc1 (document)
    doc2 (document)
    doc3 (document)
    ...
  chat_rooms/ (collection)
    room1/ (document)
      participants/ (collection)
        part_doc1 (document)
        part_doc2 (document)
        ...
    room2/ (document)
       participants/ (collection)
        part_doc1 (document)
        part_doc2 (document)
        ...
```

[image: Console view]

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown can take a while to update with the collection group names currently in your database.

In the meantime, you can [use gcloud to run the export](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import#export_specific_collections).